# Combining row number and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, row-number

In MySQL, I want to output the distinct values of a certain column in a table, together with a unique row number from 0 to the number of rows - 1. I therefore want to use the following query.

```
SET @rownr=0;

SELECT @rownr:= @rownr+1 as rank, DISTINCT a.brand_id AS brand 
FROM vda.articles a
```

The MySQL Workbench complains that the syntax is not correct: it does not expect DISTINCT at that location. Indeed, If I remove the keyword DISTINCT, the query runs. Is there a way to output a table as shown below? Note: I cannot use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, since then the variable rownr is updated too often.

```
rownr   brand
0       6
1       71
2       72
3       34
```

Comment: use it as a subquery.

Comment: @Nishanti: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I notice that it is not illegal syntax if I switch the order of rank and brand.

Comment: Of course, changing the order of fields is definitely not a syntax issue.

Comment: I mean that it is illegal if I have distinct after the rownr, and it is not illegal if I have distinct as first column in the output table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the below code. It should do the trick.. Though am not so familiar with the mysql syntax. You can get an idea with this.

I am basically getting all the distinct brands in a [sub-query](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php). And displaying it with an incremental row - number in the outer query.

```
SET @rownr=0;
SELECT @rownr:= @rownr+1 as rank, brand  from 
( select DISTINCT a.brand_id AS brand 
  FROM vda.articles a ) as B
```

Try this query as well. It will also work and it is correct as per [syntax of **DISTINCT**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php). But check if you get the right output.  I am just putting the DISTINCT keyword just after the select keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  @rownr:= @rownr+1 as rank,  
a.brand_id AS brand  FROM vda.articles a
```

Comment: Try this query. It will also work. But check if you get the right output. `SELECT DISTINCT  @rownr:= @rownr+1 as rank,  a.brand_id AS brand 
FROM vda.articles a`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in a subquery

```
set @rownr=0;
select @rownr:= @rownr+1 ,brand_id from(
    select **DISTINCT** brand_id as brand_id FROM articles
)
```